# Каким образом возможна смена физического адреса на сетевой плате?

Tags: windows, сеть, mac-address

У меня одна сетевуха меняет физический адрес после каждой перезагрузки. (Система: Windows SP Professional SP3 версия 2009).

Answer (score 1):

В Виндоуз драйвера некотрых сетевых карт позволяют менять MAC-адреса. Особенно этим славятся карты Realtek.
Необходимо прописать необходимый адрес там.Но во фразе: "меняет физический адрес после каждой перезагрузки." - не вполне понятно что к чему. То ли сбрасывается установленный Вами, то ли самопроизвольно подставляется. И вопрос - а действительно ли имеется необходимость в смена МАКа?

Comment: У меня Realtek, не встроенный, тех службу провайдера я пол дня мучал, так что там всё нормально, я ничего не менял, не настраивал в сетевухе, после каждой перезагрузки она сама каким-то непонятным образом выбирает произвольный "мак" (звонок провайдеру для настройки) выключение, и всё по новой. Другие сетевухи так себя не ведут в моём компе!

Comment: но почему он меняет "мак"!?

Comment: ну в таком случае: либо новые драйвера попробуйте скачать (сначала просто посмотрите ккак себя поведет; потом меняя МАК), либо брать другую карту на другом чипе... благо это не дорого.

Answer (score 0):

В Ubuntu вот так.

> Имеется много причин по которым вы можете захотеть вручную установить MAC адрес вашей сетевой карты. Для изменения этой опции, вам необходимо отредактировать файл `etc/network/interfaces`. Вы можете использовать любой текстовый редактор, который вам нравится.
>
> `sudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces`
>
> Вы должны увидеть строчку с вашим сетевым интерфейсом, который обычно называется eth0. Если вы используете dhcp, строчки будут приблизительно такими.
>
> `auto eth0iface eth0 inet dhcp`
>
> Просто добавьте следующую строчку ниже, чтобы получилось примерно следующее.
>
> `auto eth0iface eth0 inet dhcp       hwaddress ether 01:02:03:04:05:06`
>
> Вам необходимо перезапустить сеть или перегрузиться для достижения эффекта.
>
> `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart`

[MAC адрес](http://eloomyblog.blogspot.com/2011/08/mac.htm).

Есть ли необходимость смены мак адреса. Бывают случаи когда в этом необходимость имеется.Случай1 провайдер подключил вас с использованием мак адреса а вы поменяли сетевую карточку взамен вышедшей со строя, у меня был случай когда встроенная сетевая карточка произвольно меняла мак адреса, соответственно сеть падала, прописав мак адрес таким образом все встало на места мак адрес посылался тот который я поставил

Comment: вопрос был к топикстартеру - а так согласен, ситуации разные бывают...

Comment: Если сетевуха внешняя что парится выбрось ее и поставь другую, плохая она, может быть сбой во внутренней памяти где хранится адрес но к нему не доберешся и не поменяеш в самой карточке, а только подстановкой программно, что в винде что в линуксе